# Execute 2 batch files nonstop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am using 2 batch files that are calling each other and i don't want them to stop until i do it manually.

My issue is that when they start running, they are calling each other for approximately 2 hours.

Batch file 1(power_failure.bat):

```
python c:\alex_folder\UPS_SCRIPTS\TURN_OFF_FOR_BAT.py >>c:\alex_folder\UPS_SCRIPTS\log.txt
TIMEOUT /T 20 /NOBREAK >nul
call power_ok.bat
```

Batch file 2(power_ok.bat):

```
python c:\alex_folder\UPS_SCRIPTS\TURN_ON_FOR_BAT.py >>c:\alex_folder\UPS_SCRIPTS\log.txt
TIMEOUT /T 20 /NOBREAK >nul
call power_failure.bat
```

What can be changed in order for these scripts to run for ever until i stop them and not only 2 hours?

Comment: Your scripts make no sense. Take a look at the help information for the `Call` command, _(`call /?`)_, then explain why you are using it.

Comment: Hello @Compo. I am reading on google that i have to use "Call" in order to call a bat file inside another bat file. What i want is to run both bat files nonstop without them breaking after some time. Sorry never done this before and not sure if i am searching correctly

Comment: StackOverflow (pun intended): `call` saves the return points on a stack. Until the stack is full (overflow). You call a script that calls a script that calls a script that... You don't need (or intend) to return to the previous batch script, so skip the `call`. Question remains: why use two scripts instead of just one with a loop (`:loop`, `python ... off`, `timeout`, `phyton ... on`, `timeout`, `goto :loop`)?

Comment: Not sure of what you are trying to do, I don't see that these scripts are calling each other. What is the goal of these scripts ? seems like you are doing things in a more difficult manor .

Comment: Next question:  why employ two languages when you can do it all in python?

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. Unfortunately i can't use a loop and run both python scripts inside 1 bat file because i am using a service which turns on/off a UPS machine and this service needs 2 bat files (1 bat file for turning UPS on and 1 file for turning UPS off)

Comment: To clarify, script 1 calls script 2 and waits for that to end, returning to the next line, (which in this case doesn't exist, so would end the script). However script 2 doesn't return to it because it's last command is another call. Script 2 calls script 1 and waits for that to end, but it doesn't because of the call command again. This continues so that no `Call` is ever returned from, and there are multiple script instances using memory until it chokes/overflows, (I'd assume, for your PC, that takes around two hours).

Comment: @Compo thank you that makes sense of course. But is there any way instead of "Call"  for my case?

Comment: yes, as I said before: just skip the `call` command and execute the other batch script directly.